# Nginx - Alias file created but not working in osX after ln -s command.

Tags: macos, nginx, alias, virtualhost

I'm trying to add a simple alias file in an nginx Virtual Host system. A simple alias from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled`.

I'm using:

```
sudo ln -sfv sites-available/blog sites-enabled/
```

The alias is created. When I try to open it from Finder it says:

*The operation can't be completed because the original item for "blog" can't be found*

`nginx -t` fails because it cannot find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way softlinks work

```
sudo ln -sfv sites-available/blog sites-enabled/
```

Creates a `blog` link in `sites-enabled` folder pointing to `sites-available/blog`.

So `blog` is pointing to relative path `sites-available/blog`. Which makes the actual path to `<path>/sites-enabled/sites-available/blog` and which doesn't exists.

So do this, go inside the `sites-enabled` directory and run

```
sudo ln -sfv ../sites-available/blog blog
```

This will create the file with correct relative path